# Clear variables inside Module

Tags: scoping, map, clear

I have a function that uses `Module`. The function takes as input a `.csv` that can have as many columns as it wishes to, and it will import all of them. The user just needs to call `function[num]`, and it will import `num` columns of the `.csv`. This of course is a oversimplified version of the idea of my code. To accomplish the "unknown" number of variables I used `MapThread` like the following.

```
f[num_]:=Module[{colorlist, cnamelist},
colorlist = {};
For[i = 0, i < num, i++, 
 AppendTo[colorlist, 
  Directive[Opacity[1], 
    Defer[RGBColor] @@@ ColorData["Rainbow", 1 - i/(num - 1)]]]];
cnamelist = {};
For[i = 1, i <= num, i++, 
  AppendTo[cnamelist, StringJoin["c", ToString[i]]]];
MapThread[Set, {ToExpression[cnamelist], colorlist}];];
```

If `num` is set to 7, then it creates a list `colorlist={"c1", "c2" ... "c7"}` and then defines the variables `c1, c2... c7` with a corresponding color through `MapThread`.

Everything works, the issue is that `c1,c2, ... c7` are now defined and I cant use `MapThread` again. Since its inside a function the purpose it to use it again.

I tried adding to the function in the last line the following bit

```
For[i = 1, i <= num, i++, Clear[cnamelist[[i]] ] ]
```

But it returns the error `Clear::ssym: cnamelist[[i]] is not a symbol or a string.`

How can I clear all the variables. I have more lists like `cnamelist` in my code that needs to be cleared for it to work again, but I would assume the same procedure would work.

Comment: Use `Clear[cnamelist]` or `Delete[cnamelist , i]`, if you want to delete single elements from the list (note that the list gets shorter so that enumeration changes).

Comment: `Clear[cnamelist]` clears `cnamelist` but not the variables `c1,c2, ...c7` that are inside it. Tried putting `Delete[cnamelist , i]` instead of  `Clear[cnamelist[[i]] ]` in the `For` but nothing changed, they dont clear.

Comment: Btw.: Try to avoid `AppendTo`. Usually it involves copying the whole list. Just compare these timings:  `a = {};
Do[AppendTo[a, i], {i, 100000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
b = Range[1000000]; // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: Are there any good reasons why you want that function to define variables as a side effect instead of just returning the column data? While Mathematica does allow you to do that, it is a very unusual behavior for a function and I would consider it in almost all cases a bad idea that will almost certainly cause problems at some point. Why don't you just return the data as an array?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question. The example here is like that because I followed the same procedure than a previous portion of the code. The function imports data to be plotted from a `.csv`. The bit here is the color portion of the plots which copies the structure (code wise) of the part that imports the data. I decided to import the data like this because each column has a different label (data means something different), and the user picks the order in which to show the data in a stacked plot. So it was very relevant to know and manage the labels because order is crucial.

Comment: Hope that solves your question, again I am not sure I got it so if it didnt answer it could you rephrase it?. I executed the code as I thought it was possible to do so, maybe there was a more efficient way to do it but that's the one that came to mind and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, now I see. The problem is that `Clear` has attribute `HoldAll`. So `cnamelist[[i]]` won't evaluate to a `String`.

Try

```
cnamelist = StringJoin["c", ToString #] &/Range[num];
```

and afterwards

```
Scan[Clear, cnamelist]
```

If you want to `Clear` a single entry, you can use

```
`Clear[Evaluate[cnamelist[[i]]]]`
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am not sure what the `cnamelist` definition was, but if I use  `Scan[Clear, cnamelist]` it clears all the variables inside the list!. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to suggest some changes. First, get away from `For` loops; use `Table` instead; secondly, your application of `RGBColor` was not accomplishing anything; third, you can provide `Clear` with the *name of a variable as a string* in order to clear it, so you can `Map` `Clear` over your list of variable names after you generate them in order to clear them; fourth, you can set a list of variables to a list of values in one go, which avoids the need for `MapThread`. I would also use `Symbol["symbolname"]` rather than `ToExpression`, because the latter has much broader scope and will likely be slower. Finally, I would make sure that `num` is an integer, just to sanitize the input.

```
Clear[f]
f[num_Integer] := Module[
  {colorlist, cnamelist},
  colorlist =
    Table[
      Directive[Opacity[1], ColorData["Rainbow", 1 - i/(num - 1)]],
      {i, 0, num - 1}
    ];
  cnamelist = Table["c" <> ToString[i], {i, num}];
  Clear /@ cnamelist;
  Evaluate[Symbol /@ cnamelist] = colorlist
]
```

---

Ultimately, I would also suggest using indexed variables (e.g. `c[2]`) rather than composite names (i.e. `c2`). The indexed variables are easier to deal with programmatically. See the modified `fArray` below:

```
Clear[fArray]

fArray[num_Integer] := Module[
  {colorlist},
  colorlist =
    Table[
      Directive[Opacity[1], ColorData["Rainbow", 1 - i/(num - 1)]],
      {i, 0, num - 1}
    ];
  Clear[c];
  Evaluate[Array[c, num]] = colorlist
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's a lot of information that I will try to get through. I have to admit I am by no means an experienced Mathematica user. The rest of the code of the function is covered with `For` loops, I will see how I can change them to `Tables`. In another part of the code I have to use `ToExpression[ , Hold]`, that took a really long time to get working so I wouldnt touch that but in this case I will follow your suggestion about `MapThread`. I will have to read a lot about everything you said. Thank you so much!

Comment: I decided to go the way I did with `c1, c2, .... c3` because in other parts of the code I required a better differentiation of names of the variables.